# How to do component alignment with Vaadin Declarative UI?

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

The 'component-alignment' is recognized, however not respected. Note the ':'-prefix, because this property has to be set on the parent Component.

```
<v-panel size-full>
   <v-vertical-layout size-full>
      <v-horizontal-layout width="100%">
         <v-image source="theme://logo.gif" :component-alignment="MIDDLE_RIGHT" />
    <v-menu-bar _id="menu" width="100%" :component-alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" />
      </v-horizontal-layout>
   </v-vertical-layout>
</v-panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.declarative.html#application.declarative.attributes.parent):

> Certain settings, such as a component's alignment in a layout, are not done in the component itself, but in the layout. Attributes prefixed with colon (:) are passed to the containing component, with the component as a target parameter. For example, :expand="1" given for a component c is equivalent to calling setExpandRatio(c, 1) for the containing layout.

```
<v-vertical-layout size-full>
  <!-- Align right in the containing layout -->
  <v-label width-auto :right>Hello!</v-label>
  ...
```

What it does not say, at least for now, is that in order to get a `MIDDLE_RIGHT` alignment, you need to specify both of them individually, like:

```
<v-button _id="loginButton" style-name="primary" :middle :right>Sign in</v-button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that ":component-alignment" is not reported as wrong syntax.

Comment: @rmuller No problem, glad I could help. I'm not sure but I think the Vaadin parser will silently ignore such _extra attributes_ at runtime, and unless you have your IDE validate the templates with an XSD, you won't be able to know during development either.